# COVID-19 tests for travel from UK to Italy/France

Tags: customs-and-immigration, france, covid-19, italy

If you are unvaccinated, do you need to take a supervised antigen test to travel to Italy or France? Or is it a self test that you do at home?

Comment: When do you plan to travel? (Rules are changing and I am not sure about the dates of change.)

Comment: End of June, but worried that they might extend their travel rules like Spain did recently

Comment: Have you checked the websites for France and Italy linked from https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/france/entry-requirements and https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/italy/entry-requirements? Requirements change, a reliable answer can’t be given now for travel in 2+ months’ time

Answer (score 3):

If you are travelling at the end of June, you won't need to show any proof of vaccination, since Italy had updated entry requirements on June 1, 2022.

"As of 1 June, COVID-19 travel restrictions are lifted in Italy. Providing proof of vaccination, recovery from COVID-19 or negative test results is no longer required."

You can read more [here](https://ambtallinn.esteri.it/ambasciata_tallinn/en/ambasciata/news/dall_ambasciata/2021/10/covid-19-per-coloro-che-devono.html).

Hope it helps and enjoy your trip :)